# Eliminating duplicates from SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be the best way to return one item from each `id` instead of all of the other items within the table.  Currently the query below returns all manufacturers

```
SELECT m.name
FROM  `default_ps_products` p
INNER JOIN  `default_ps_products_manufacturers` m ON p.manufacturer_id = m.id
```

Comment: So you'd like one row from `default_ps_products_manufacturers` for each row in `default_ps_products`?  Do you have preference for a certain row or can it be a random one?

Comment: @Andomar Can be random just want all manufacturers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my question by using the `DISTINCT` value in my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name, m.id
FROM  `default_ps_products` p
INNER JOIN  `default_ps_products_manufacturers` m ON p.manufacturer_id = m.id
ORDER BY m.name
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 4 main ways I can think of to delete duplicate rows
method 1
delete all rows bigger than smallest or less than greatest rowid value.  Example

```
delete from tableName a where rowid> (select min(rowid) from tableName b where a.key=b.key and a.key2=b.key2)
```

method 2
usually faster but you must recreate all indexes, constraints and triggers afterward..
pull all as distinct to new table then drop 1st table and rename new table to old table name
example.

```
create table t1 as select distinct * from t2; drop table t1; rename t2 to t1;
```

method 3
delete uing where exists based on rowid.  example

```
delete from tableName a where exists(select 'x' from tableName b where a.key1=b.key1 and a.key2=b.key2 and b.rowid >a.rowid)  Note if nulls are on column use nvl on column name.
```

method 4
collect first row for each key value and delete rows not in this set.  Example

```
delete from tableName a where rowid not in(select min(rowid) from tableName b group by key1, key2)
```

note that you don't have to use nvl for method 4

Comment: I do not want to delete them I just do not want to show them in the result

Comment: `nvl` is Oracle, but the question is for MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Using DISTINCT often is a bad practice. It may be a sing that there is something wrong with your SELECT statement, or your data structure is not normalized.

In your case I would use this (in assumption that default_ps_products_manufacturers has unique records).

```
SELECT m.id, m.name
FROM  default_ps_products_manufacturers m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM default_ps_products p WHERE p.manufacturer_id = m.id)
```

Or an equivalent query with IN:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name
FROM  default_ps_products_manufacturers m
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT p.manufacturer_id FROM default_ps_products p)
```

The only thing - between all possible queries it is better to select the one with the better execution plan. Which may depend on your vendor and/or physical structure, statistics, etc... of your data base.

I think in most cases EXISTS will work better.